# responsive fixed-top navbar when expanded fills up screen, hides some of the nav-links, and does not scroll

Tags: html, scroll, bootstrap-4, nav, overlap

I have created a fixed-top bootstrap 4 navbar that is expanded on large screens, and collapsed on the others. I have also added `padding-top` to the `<body>` to prevent the navbar from overlapping the main body content.

However, on smaller screens when the collapsed navbar is expanded using the hamburger button, it expands and fills the screen. Some of the nav-links then become hidden (i.e. outside the display). Moreover,scrolling does not scroll the navbar, but only the main body content which is beneath the navbar.

Is it possible to compress the navbar to not take up more than the screen size? Or, how do I enable a scrollable navbar?

Added pictures below to show the issue.

Here is a snap in mobile view without expanding the navbar:
[image: collapsed navbar]

And here is the snap to illustrate the problem that the navbar takes up the whole viewport, and that there are still links but "outside" the display:
[image: expanded navbar overlaps]

Here is JSFiddle if needed:
https://jsfiddle.net/suhaib47/ef37ht06/6/

---

## Edit:

After using the answer provided by @Zim, I now face a different problem. In the desktop screen, the navbar is displayed properly. However, when I click on the nav-items/nav-links which pop open a dropdown list, the dropdown list stays within the navbar and there is a scroll bar for scrolling the navbar. How do I make the dropdown menu to show over the navbar content, while at the same time it can be scrolled but only when the navbar is collapsed.

I've included a picture to show what I mean:
[image]

The scrollbar seen in the picture is for the navbar.

Comment: can you show your working code or a fiddle for better understanding?

Comment: @TarangRathod I've included the fiddle link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a max-height on the `.navbar-collapse` that's equal to viewport height minus the body top padding...

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed-top .navbar-collapse {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 4.5em);
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/1KXwX3I1Mh

Comment: This works. I had started to consider using media queries to set `max-height` but this is much better. If i wanted to leave a bit of space between the navbar and the bottom of the screen, I should just subtract a few units more right? PS my apologies for not using codeply :)

Comment: i have updated my question with a new issue regarding the navbar links popping open a dropdown menu that I faced after using your answer

Comment: I answered the original question. Please ask a separate question (if there are no duplicates) for the Navbar layout issue.

Comment: Commenting so I can find this answer when I need it later :P